# How do I animate a face to change color over time?

Tags: animation, keyframes

How do I paint a face so that the color changes over a specific time frame?

Comment: by 'time frame', do you mean over the course of a part of an animation?  For 'color' are you talking about the face being all a single color and that color varying over time?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can change colors over time like this:

Go to the frame where you want the color change to start.

e.g. frame 20

[image]

Now hover your cursor over the color and hit "I". This enters a keyframe for the color.

[image]

Choose now the keyframe where you want to end the color animation.

e.g. frame 120:

[image]

now choose another color, hover again the cursor over the new color and press "I" again.

[image]

result:

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the response.  I understand and am able to animate color change now.

Comment: Glad I could help. Please check the checkmark left of my answer if it helped you.